# How do I get rid of the Play buttons in a Silverlight/Expression Media Player?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-3.0, expression-blend

I'm using an **ExpressionMediaPlayer** to play live streams. Obviously for this I don't need a play/pause button.

Is there already a predefined way to select which controls to show, or is the correct way to edit the control template and just remove them? Trying to keep everything as out of the box as possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a predefined way to show/hide certain controls (please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).

The quickest way would be to edit a new copy of the template and simply set the controls you don't want to Visibility="Collapsed"

Comment: That worked, and was surprisingly a lot less destructive editing a copy of the control template than I expected!

Comment: Yup, Templates are really cool ... it makes controls incredibly easy to customize and style.